# Expectation of an Expectation

Tags: expected-value, conditional-expectation

I need to solve two exercises:

1. Calculate V[u<sub>i</sub>|x<sub>i</sub>] **using** E[y<sub>i</sub>|x<sub>i</sub>] and u<sub>i</sub> = y<sub>i</sub> - E[y<sub>i</sub>].
2. Calculate E[$y^2$|x<sub>i</sub>].

Information given for the exercise: 
E[$u^2$|x<sub>i</sub>] = V[y<sub>i</sub>|x<sub>i</sub>] 
E[$u^2$|x<sub>i</sub>] = V[y<sub>i</sub>|x<sub>i</sub>] because E[u<sub>i</sub>|x<sub>i</sub>]

There are also a values given for E[y<sub>i</sub>] = 2λ<sub>i</sub>, V[y<sub>i</sub>] = 2$λ^2$ and λ<sub>i</sub> = (e$^{xβ}$)/2

What I know: 
V[y<sub>i</sub>|x<sub>i</sub>] = V[$y^2$|x<sub>i</sub>] = E[$y^2$|x<sub>i</sub>] - $(E[y|x])^2$

It would be easy to set the value for E[y<sub>i</sub>] into u and square it. Afterward set the solution into E[$u^2$|x<sub>i</sub>] and V[y<sub>i</sub>|x<sub>i</sub>] would be solved. 
Obviously I wouldn't use E[y<sub>i</sub>|x<sub>i</sub>] in this case, so I tried it by rearranging terms, but often end at a point where they cancel each other out and I am back at the beginning.

**So my question is**: How do I properly derive V[u<sub>i</sub>|x<sub>i</sub>] and E[$y^2$|x]. Especially important for me is how to link it to E[y<sub>i</sub>|x<sub>i</sub>].

Answer (score 1):

In the part where you write "what I know" it does not make sense to say $V(y|x)=V(y^2|x)$.

1. $V(u|x)=V(y-E(y)|x)=V(y|x)$ (because E(y) is a constant). This in turn is $E(y^2|x)-\left[E(y|x)\right]^2$.
2. Also, $E(y^2|x)=V(y|x)+\left[E(y|x)\right]^2$

But, I am not clear how all these conditional expectations and variances tie into the particular values. One way to do it is for (2), $\frac{e^{2x\beta}}{2}+e^{2x\beta}=\frac{3}{2}e^{2x\beta}$. And for (1), we can go directly from $V(y|x)=\frac{e^{2x\beta}}{2}$.